# How to create the second player/Computer

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I am working to create a two player dice game, where the player can either play with another user or the computer. i am having a hard time figuring out how to create a two player game. I am not sure if i have to create separate classes for each user and then create an object of that class to have two separate players or if i just have to create a variable like

```
static int player = 1;
```

and assign it to specific areas and use modulus to figure out which player is up.

Also, under my `roll_Btn` method you will see that i am trying to get it to switch to the next user when the dice rolls a "1" and clear the specified fields, which it does, but the then program ends on me once i try and roll the dice again. See below for my code. thank you for your help and guidance.

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static int player = 1;
    private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneNameTxt.Text = diceFrm.player1.ToUpper();
        twoNameTxt.Text = diceFrm.player2.ToUpper();
    }

    private void endBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diceFrm end = new diceFrm();
        end.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void standBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneScoreTxt.Text = totalTxt.Text;
    }

    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(turnsTxt.Text);
        int t2 = t1 + 1;
        turnsTxt.Text = t2.ToString();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice = rand.Next(1, 7);
        rollTxt.Text = dice.ToString();
        int d1 = Convert.ToInt32(totalTxt.Text);
        int d2 = d1 + dice;
        totalTxt.Text = d2.ToString();
        if(dice == 1)
        {
            player++;
            rollTxt.Text = String.Empty;
            turnsTxt.Text = String.Empty;
            totalTxt.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
    private void oneScoreTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int score1 = Convert.ToInt32(oneScoreTxt.Text);
        int score2 = Convert.ToInt32(twoScoreTxt.Text);

        if (score1 >= 100 || score2 >= 100)
        {
            whatLbl.Text = "Winner";
        }
        else
        {
            whatLbl.Text = "Turn";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You set turnsTxt.Text = String.Empty; and not assign this to a string representation of a valid integer, and when the button is clicked again, you try to convert the textbox value to an integer with int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(turnsTxt.Text);

Comment: thank you, works perfectly. @OguzOzgul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ogul Ozgul said,

```
    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        if (dice == 1)
        {
            ...
            turnsTxt.Text = String.Empty;
            ...
        }
    }
```

When you roll a 1, your turnsTxt.Text = String.Empty, hence when the next time you roll,

```
    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(turnsTxt.Text); // program crash
        ...
    }
```

your program will crash horribly.

Solution: I will recommend you use TryParse instead of Convert throughout your code. It will be much more robust.

Eg.

```
    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int t1 = 0;
        int.TryParse(turnsTxt.Text, out t1)
        int t2 = t1 + 1;
        turnsTxt.Text = t2.ToString(); 
        ...
        //rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much. sorry for the late response. works perfectly. @interceptwind